# MongoError : command createIndexes requires authentication - mongodb npm

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a project that I recently put in a production server (not live, but different from my development environment). I configured a mongoDB server with a password authentication.

When I start my Nodejs Application, my usual code retrieve correctly my mongoDB server, returning a client.db object successfully.

But I also have an error popping-in. Something that is not called inside my Nodejs application apparently.

```
[ERROR]  { MongoError: command createIndexes requires authentication
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/myaccount/myapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:460:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at processMessage (/home/myaccount/myapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:368:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/myaccount/myapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:537:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'command createIndexes requires authentication',
  code: 13,
  codeName: 'Unauthorized',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

nothing in the error is pointing toward something I created, it's only about the mongodb npm library. It also giving this error even if a delete every MongoDB connexion related code (but not the mongodb library load).

Do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: have you created any users?  What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I created one user inside my main Database "ProjectDatabase" with root permissions, but also one in the admin database with also the root permissions. I can connect with MongoDB compass successfully, and like I said, my logs output correctly the DB object given after the connexion. And then the error arrives from nowhere. My connexion string look like that : mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/ProjectDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it's my fault. I had another connexion point that I didn't changed from my express sessions. It's fixed now.

It's just weird the error didn't point toward that module..

Comment: I had the same issue. My problem was I was using MongoStore for managing sessions and I didn't authenticate that haha.